# .table-cell and .table display not working well on IE

Tags: html, css

I seem to have an issue with displaying a .table and .table-cell display in IE browsers (works fine on Chrome).

This is how it looks on Chrome (how it should look):
[image]

Here is how it looks on IE browsers (9 and above).
The cells are not positioned next to each other, they are positioned below each other:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="Tab">
     <div class="row">
         <input type="button" runat="server" class="Tabbutton iconInterview TabbuttonActive" />
         <input type="button" runat="server" class="Tabbutton iconScore " />
         <input type="button" runat="server" class="Tabbutton iconInfo" />
         <input type="button" runat="server" class="Tabbutton iconActions" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Here are the CSS elements:

```
.Tab
{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    display:table;
}
.Tabbutton
{
    height:40px;
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    display:table-cell;
    width:25%;
    border-top:none;
    border-right:none;
}
.TabbuttonActive {
    border-bottom:none;
    background-color:white;
}
.row{display:table-row;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: table` and `display: table-cell` are supported from IE11 http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell

I don't know your case, what do you whant to do with these buttons, but is it possible for you, to use simple `display: block` and `float: left` ?

```css
.Tab
{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
}
.Tabbutton
{
    height:40px;
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    border-top:none;
    border-right:none;
}
.TabbuttonActive {
    border-bottom:none;
    background-color:white;
}
.btnCol {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="Tab">
     <div class="row">
         <span class="btnCol">
           <input type="button" runat="server" class="Tabbutton iconInterview TabbuttonActive" />
         </span>
         <span class="btnCol">
           <input type="button" runat="server" class="Tabbutton iconScore " />
         </span>
         <span class="btnCol">
           <input type="button" runat="server" class="Tabbutton iconInfo" />
         </span>
         <span class="btnCol">
           <input type="button" runat="server" class="Tabbutton iconActions" />
         </span>                         
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I rather not use a div on each of the buttons... Is there a more elegant way to do this ?

Comment: BTW it happens on IE 11 also

Comment: use `<span>` instead or `<label>` - there is nothing wrong with that. You want to create a layout, don't do this with inputs, they are not for that

Comment: Thanks. I changed the layout as you suggested and it looks good now.